# iOS Google Cloud Storage API Service Account Access

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to access Google Cloud Storage using a service account from iOS.  The iOS application writes images to Rails and I've used a service account with the ruby apis to save the image to Google Storage.  I'm trying to read those images from iOS but it seems like the ability is not there and I'm not sure why.  The only way I can make it work is to use an API key and set the predefinedAcl to 'publicRead'.  This means my application's images are open to the internet.

What am I missing?  Is there a reason this functionality isn't there in the iOS library?  Any plans in the future?

Thanks

Comment: If you ship your application with the service account, security is compromised. Any user that downloads the application could extract the key.

Comment: @jterrace But then.. How are we supposed to use a Service Account with iOS-applications? Thomas, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No.  I left it as publicRead for now, rather than forcing them to go through my app server where I can use the service account... I just don't want to pay for that traffic through there. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you are heavily compromising your security while following a really bad practice. Here's are two strategies on how to fix it:

- When you save your images to Google Storage, you should create a [signed URL](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-ruby/#/docs/v0.10.0/gcloud/storage/file?method=signed_url-instance) for the same and use that as end point for clients/app. OR
- Save original Google Storage URLs to user's account, inaccessible via user api, and during runtime when a request for image is received, generate a short duration based signed URL.

Service key based approach is really faulty as first you are giving away your project credentials and moreover you can never even expire those keys since they might be used in one of many end devices.

Comment: Perfectly valid point for a public app. But in the case of a purely non-public app that is being used to capture telemetry, a service key is really convenient. I'm currently looking into this for this reason.